# how to disable mouse clicking only on the last column of the jtable?

Tags: events, jtable

i want to make sure that only the last column of the jtable could not be clicked by mouse or button as it only to display results from other rows.

i have tried using iscellEditable but the mouse can still click on the last column thus changing data due to my mouse event.

here is my code:

```
               table = new JTable(){
               @Override
               public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
               }
              };
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
                table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                getContentPane().add(table);
                final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Student Name","Student ID"},0);
                int q = table.getSelectedColumn();
                int r = table.getSelectedRow();
                table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                String click1 = (String) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getColumnCount()-1) ;
                int click2 = Integer.parseInt(click1);
                int q = table.getSelectedColumn();
                int r = table.getSelectedRow();
                Object p = table.getValueAt(r,q);
                String t = null;
                String  b = p.toString();

                switch (b) {
                case "1":  t = "L";

                       break;
                case "L":  t = "0";
                           click2++;
                       break;
                case "0":  t = "H"; 
                           click2--;
                       break;
                case "H":  t = "1"; 
                       break;
                default: t = b;
                break;
                }

                String click3 = Integer.toString(click2);

                tableModel.setValueAt(click3,r,table.getColumnCount()-1);
                tableModel.setValueAt(t,r,q);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning if the clicked column is last one?

when you get `int q = table.getSelectedColumn();`

then add `if (q == 'last_column_id') { return;}` where `'last_column_id'` is the id of the column. For example if there are 5 columns las's id is 4, so if selected column is 4 return.

You can use `table.getColumnCount() - 1` to get this id.

Comment: it says invalid character constant for 'last_column_num'

Comment: Sorry by 'last_column_num' I meant the last colunm id, if there are 5 columns it should be 4. So if you select column 4 return. You can use `table.getColumnCount() - 1` to get this id.

Comment: Even if you do the same at the `setCellSelectionEnabled` method?